# Api recebendo data com mês e dia trocados

Tags: javascript, c#, json, vue.js, asp.net-core

Tenho uma classe:

```
public class Filtros{
    public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFinal { get; set; }
    //outros campos...
}
```

Tenho uma API C# que recebe a classe:

```
[HttpPost("ObterProvisoes")]
public JsonResult ObterProvisoes(Filtros filtros)
{
    //recebe mm/dd/yyyy
}
```

Então envio o objeto Filtros preenchido:

```
var filtros = {
          DataInicial: self.DataInicial, // dd/mm/yyyy
          DataFinal: self.DataFinal // dd/mm/yyyy
}

$.post("/api/RelatorioFinanceiro/ObterProvisoes", filtros, function () {

}).done(function (response) {
        //funcoes
});
```

Quando eu envio o objeto preenchido a data esta no formato dd/mm/yyyy, mas a api recebe como mm/dd/yyyy. 
Tem algum modo de configurar a API ou o projeto (asp.net core 1.1) para não alterar a data? Ou informar que o formato da data é dd/mm/yyyy na api?

OBS: não quero usar funções no javascript que convertem a data, pois teria que fazer isso cada vez que tivesse uma data no projeto, acho errado, quero resolver de uma vez só, que tenha efeito em todas.

Comment: Relacionada: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format).

Comment: @Aesir, precisa incluir o que vc já fez/ tentou fazer. Colocar o código fonte, etc. Da uma olhada em [ask]

Comment: estou complementando, já atualizo.

Comment: formata sua data para ela ir na api com o formato dela

Comment: Provavelmente a API não foi você quem fez e você apenas consume ela, certo? Nesse caso, provavelmente a API utiliza formato americano para datas e você não tem como mudar isso. Meu conselho é formatar a data antes de enviar para o formato mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @BrunoH. Não quero alterar no lado do javascript, pois quero uma solução global.

Comment: @Perozzo A API é minha, quero um modo de configura-lá para receber as datas em formato BR.

Comment: @BrunoH. Preciso de um modo de configurar isso, pois se o dia informado for maior que 12 ele recebe como 1 na API, Pois não existe mês 13 por exemplo, não funcionando a conversão do lado da API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando estiver trabalhando com datas no `client-side`, tente utilizar sempre o formato de data [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), que ao ser enviado para o webApi será transformado corretamente pelo `jsonSerializer` independente da localização configurada no lado do cliente.

O formato de data definido na *ISO* é `yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss.sssz`, e o próprio javascript tem um método para transformar um objeto do tipo `Date` para uma `string` neste formato, com o [.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

> OBS: não quero usar funções no javascript que convertem a data, pois
>   teria que fazer isso cada vez que tivesse uma data no projeto, acho
>   errado, quero resolver de uma vez só, que tenha efeito em todas.

Quanto ao comentário acima, acredito que você deva se perguntar sobre como funcionará um sistema que lide com diversas nacionalidades e formatos de data. Adotar um padrão de comunicação (como a *ISO8601*) pode te trazer uma complexidade menor do que precisar trocar os padrões de data do teu sistema de acordo com quem está realizando a requisição.

Relacionados SOen:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36066269/4223174
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36701826/4223174

Comment: Estudando sobre a sua resposta e analisando as opções que tenho para resolver este problema, realmente a sua é a melhor!

Comment: Eu já tive bastante bronca com datetime lidando com Web Api, tem até um artigo legal sobre porque o CultureInfo não afeta diretamente as datas recebidas nos controllers. Vou ver se encontro para te passar aqui